Help identify British miniseries about best friends
Maybe someone can help me identify a British miniseries:
I think it's late 90's or early 2000 but not sure.
It's about a woman and a man, best friends, about 30, colleagues (I think most of the scenes are in the lighted, open spaced, office).
She is married, about to be divorced but having second thoughts. (There is a scene that her husband comes to the office to give her the divorce papers) 
He is chubby (not the typical romantic comedy hero), maybe younger then her, in love with her and she doesn't know.
Before the end some other woman at the office tells her she (the other woman) is in love with him, but he is very much in love with the heroine, and she doesn't even suspect.
Another scene I remember is when the woman is telling the man about a plan for a romantic weekend, and he think she suggest him to go together, until he founds out she means with her husband.

It sounds like Rescue Me (not to be confused with the Denis Leary show), though I admit I remember only glimpses of it. It was a UK show that only ran for one season on 2002. From TV.com:

Katie Nash (played by Sally Phillips) is a featured magazine writer for "Eden" having romantic problems in her life. After her marriage failed because she slept with her husband's friend, Katie tries to get back on track. The story also follows her friends from the office where she works - the chief subeditor, Eddie, has some feelings for Katie, when in the meantime, Mel, the Editor's PA, likes Eddie.

When the show starts, she's divorcing her husband but is having second thoughts; Eddie is chubby, and in one episode, she's having dreams about Eddie, but decides to take her soon to be ex-husband on a romantic weekend instead. Here are Katie and Eddie:


WOW! Thank you so much!  This is the one.  I was actually very doubtful if this is something anyone would recognize. Of course I didn't expect it to be so fast. I was looking for this for a long time. Thanks again! :-)
